# Infinite while loop implementing Remove function using Open Addressing on Hash Table - Python

Tags: python, hashtable

I am trying to implement the `remove` function with linear probing on a hash table.

I am having a problem with that, when I try to call the function remove it enter an infinite loop.

How can I fix that problem??

I have written the function taking the pseudocode:

```
remove(t, k):
    z = 0
    repeat
        x = hash_function (k, z)
        if hash_table[x] == k:
             hash_table[x] = deleted return x
        z = z+1
     until hash_table[x] == NIL or z == m
     return NIL
```

This is the code into a class:

```
class lin_prob:
    def __init__(self, table_size):
        
        self.hash_table = [None]*table_size
        self.n_prime = 109169
        self.a = random.randint(2, self.prime-1)
        self.b = random.randint(2, self.prime-1)
        self.n_keys = 0
    
    def remove(self, k):
        z = 0
        while self.hash_table[x] != None or z < len (hash_table):
            x = self.hash_function(k)
            if self.hash_table[x] == k:
                self.hash_table[x] = "deleted"
                return x
            else :
                z = z+1
        return "NIL"

    
    def hash_function(self, k):
        return ((self.a*k + self.b) % self.prime_number) % len(self.hash_table)
    
    def len(self):
        return self.n_keys
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to negate the `until` condition to create a `while` condition, you must change the `or` to an `and`:

```
while self.hash_table[x] != None and z < len (hash_table):
    ...
```

Also, you code cannot work because `x` is unknown in your `remove` method.

Answer (score 1):

The problem arises with the condition you put into the while loop
`while self.hash_table[x] != None and z < len (hash_table):`
because the negation of equal `==` is not equal `!=`. I believe it will fix your problem.